# Sort emails by time in mutt

Tags: mutt

Currently my threads in mutt are sorted by descending order of date, but emails on the same date are sorted in ascending order of time.

This is what I have in my .muttrc:

```
set index_format="%4C %Z %{%b %d} %-15.15L (%4l) %s"'
set sort_aux = reverse-last-date-received  # like gmail
set date_format = "%m/%d/%t"
```

Do you guys have any ideas for this? I tried searching, but I am not sure if anyone else found this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not all of the combinations give useful results, but this may help:

```
set sort_aux = last-date-received                           
set sort = reverse-threads
```

The entries have the requested ordering, though threads look odd:

[image]

I'm more used to this (no reverses):

[image]